# My husband and I are Croatian citizens. What do we need to submit for a visa application for residency in Germany?

Tags: visa, germany, resident-permit, eu-citizens, residency

My husband and I are Croatian citizens. What do we need to submit for a visa application for residency in Germany?

Answer (score 2):

> What do we need to submit for a visa application for residency in Germany?

None.  As EU citizens, you cannot get German visas.  As noted in the other answer, you have to register when you move there, but the only document you need is a Croatian passport or ID card.  This is explicit in the free movement directive, [2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32004L0038).  Article 6(1):

> Union citizens shall have the right of residence on the territory of another Member State for a period of up to three months without any conditions or any formalities other than the requirement to hold a valid identity card or passport.

To remain for more than three months, you must look at Article 7, which lays out four qualifying conditions.  Each of you must meet at least one condition to qualify.  It says in part:

> Right of residence for more than three months
>
> 1. All Union citizens shall have the right of residence on the territory of another Member State for a period of longer than three months if they:
>
>    (a) are workers or self-employed persons in the host Member State; or
>
>    (b) have sufficient resources for themselves and their family members not to become a burden on the social assistance system of the host Member State during their period of residence and have comprehensive sickness insurance cover in the host Member State; or
>
>    (c)
>      — are enrolled at a private or public establishment, accredited or financed by the host Member State on the basis of its legislation or administrative practice, for the principal purpose of following a course of study, including vocational training; and
>
>    — have comprehensive sickness insurance cover in the host Member State and assure the relevant national authority, by means of a declaration or by such equivalent means as they may choose, that they have sufficient resources for themselves and their family members not to become a burden on the social assistance system of the host Member State during their period of residence; or
>
>    (d) are family members accompanying or joining a Union citizen who satisfies the conditions referred to in points (a), (b) or (c).

Because of the fourth condition, only one of you needs to find a job (or be self-sufficient or be a student) in order for both of you to be able to stay.

However, you should be aware that you may have a fairly difficult time moving to Germany unless you wait for the current [travel restrictions](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268) to be relaxed.

Answer (score -1):

As European Union citizens, you do not require a residence permit to live in another European Union country.

Some countries (like Poland) require you to apply for a residence certificate after taking up residence.

Germany does not, but you are required to register at the local registration office (Meldebehörde) in the same way as a German citizen must.

However, you must be able to sustain yourself in that country.

So in general, having an income that is sufficient for your needs is the main condition.

So if you make demands on social services soon after arrival, questions will then be asked if you fullfill these conditions.

Comment: "So in general, having an income that is sufficient for your needs is the main condition": this is a reasonable but somewhat imprecise summary of the actual requirements.  For example, an EU citizen in another EU country who is employed in that country may not be subjected to a means test.  It doesn't matter how much the job pays: if the person is employed, the person may remain.

Comment: @phoog The next sentence implies just that.

Comment: Suppose someone has 8 minor children and a minimum wage job.  Is that "an income sufficient for your needs"?  I suspect not.  Yet such a person must be allowed to remain.

Comment: @phoog That is very doubtful for someone that has just arrived.

Comment: @phog The general rule (set by the Bundesverfassungsgericht) is 3 months of work. After that social services are available and being asked to leave unlikly. I knew a UK citizenm, who up to then had worked only 6 months (where 12 months was required) and was asked to leave. Then thus ruling came out and that order was revolked.

Comment: Were those people seeking social services while they were still employed, or did the case concern unemployment benefit or some other benefit after the termination of employment?  It is a significant difference.  Do you have any references for a specific case or cases?

Comment: @phoog You are the one contriting that *DIRECTIVE 2004/38/EC Article 7 (b)* can not be applied, so you should supply the proof. **have sufficient resources for themselves and their family members not to become a burden on the social assistance system of the host Member State during their period of residence and have comprehensive sickness insurance cover in the host Member State;**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105911/discussion-between-phoog-and-mark-johnson).